# When to return a pointer, pass a pointer as a parameter or not use them at all?

Tags: c, pointers

I am currently experimenting with C, and I am having a really hard time understanding how to use pointers in functions. I understand what is happening when I initialize a pointer then dereferencing it, however, I get a little confused when I have to use them in functions as follows:

I have three functions here, but I do not know exactly when to use which. I am still relatively new to C.

```
int returnSomething(int a, int b)
int returnSomething(int *ptrA, int *ptrB)
int* returnSomething(int *ptrA, int *ptrB);
```

edit:

Is there a major difference between the three?

Comment: There is really no way to decide without more specifics on the requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to adapt your usage to every situation.

The first case, you take two ints by value as parameters and return an int. Because your parameters are by value, any changes applied to them will only have function scope.

For example:

```
int returnSomething(int a, int b)
{
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    return 0;
}

//....

int x = 3;
int y = 4;
returnSomething(a,b);
// x will still be 3, y will still be 4
```

In the second case, because you pass parameters as pointers, you will be able to change the values.

```
int returnSomething(int* a, int* b)
{
    *a = 0;
    *b = 0;
    return 0;
}

//....

int x = 3;
int y = 4;
returnSomething(&a,&b);
// x and y will be 0 here
```

The third case, besides passing parameters by their pointer, you return a pointer to an int. This means inside the function you have to allocate memory and free it when you are done. I don't recommend using this, there usually are workarounds to doing it.

```
int* returnSomething(int* a, int* b)
{
   int* x = malloc(sizeof(int));
   *x = 1;
   return x;
}

//....

int x = 3;
int y = 4;
int* z = returnSomething(&a,&b);
free(z);
```

The answer is, it depends on what you want to do. If you need to change the parameters value in the method, pass by reference or by pointer. I wouldn't recommend using the last method.

Also, this applies because you're dealing with POD types. If you have your own struct, it will be more efficient passing it by pointer or returning a pointer, since a new copy won't have to be made.

Comment: Wow, this really helped clear things up! I will be trying to creating struct soon, so most likely I will have to use the third method. Thanks!

Comment: Since you allocated it on the heap, it will keep the value it was assigned in the function, so 1. Also, it's possible that also after free(z) it will still contain 1, since free will basically tell the system it can reuse that memory, and not neceserally delete it. But it might :)

Comment: Since 3 and 4 was passed into the function, because you did nothing with it and only allocated 1 to x, int* z only contains 1 right? So let's say you did int* x = malloc(sizeof(int *a)) then returned x, would the value now be 3?

Comment: If you mean int* x = malloc(sizeof(int)); *x = 1; x *= a; then yes.

Comment: int* x = malloc(sizeof(int * a)); makes no sense.

Comment: That's what I meant ;) This syntax was confusing about 10 minutes ago! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Let's explain **passing by reference** to you first; it's a lot less complicated to deal with.

Say you have:

```
int increment(int &a)
{
    a = a + 1;
    return a;
}

increment(foo); // foo = foo + 1;
```

(**NOTE:** To make it easier to understand, I've sacrificed some 'correctness'.)

This does two things:

- The third line increments `a` by `1`. But notice - we put `&a` in the function declaration. This means that the value passed to `increment()` "by reference" is also incremented by `1`. In other words, `foo` increases by `1`, just like `a`.
- The fourth line returns the *value* of `a` - a number, such as `1`, `2`, `42`, `-21`, etc.

**One more thing:** Passing by reference is **C++**; you can't use it in C, but it's a good concept to learn before you start messing with pointers.

---

Passing a pointer is basically just **passing by value**... except you're passing the location in memory (`0x12345678`), as opposed to the actual `foo`.

```
int pincrement(int *p)
{
    *p = *p + 1;
    return *p;
}

pincrement(&foo); // foo = foo + 1;
```

This does the same thing as our first program - it increments the value of `foo`.

- The `&foo` tells you the address of `foo` in memory. This information is passed to `p`. So:

  ```
  p = &foo;
  ```
- On the third line, the value pointed to by `*p` is incremented. In other words, `foo` is incremented by `1`.
- The fourth line returns the *value* of `foo` - a number, such as `1`, `2`, `42`, `-21`, etc.

---

For returning pointers, you could use them to return `string`s:

```
char *HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello, World!";
}
```

Comment: There are no references in `c`

Comment: Alright. So let's say I used int a, instead of the reference, &a, what difference would this make?

Comment: @balki Err... yeah, it says that.

Comment: @diesel You wouldn't be able to modify the value of `foo`. You only pass pointers (or by references) when you want to modify the value of `foo`.

Comment: @diesel Think of &a in as meaning "The address of a"

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question has more to do with memory considerations and good code design i.e. whether you'd like to conserve resources and if you are aware of what's going on in your code at any one instance in time.
1) when you pass by value `( int returnSomething(int a, int b) )` every parameter is a copy and any changes made to them doesn't affect the original variable outside of the function (The parameters have function scope), and the function returns a value which you can then use to initialise a variable.

2) When you pass by pointer, you're **passing an address to a location in memory** so remember that as a matter of good code design you have to insulate that location against modification by another external (lock semantics) process. This especially applies to your provided examples:

```
int returnSomething(int *ptrA, int *ptrB)
int* returnSomething(int *ptrA, int *ptrB);
```

wherein changes made to **`*ptrA and *ptrB`** within the function persists after the function exits. The only difference between the two is that one of the functions return a value which you can then use to initialise a variable `( int returnSomething(int *ptrA, int *ptrB) )`, the other returns another address to a location in memory that maybe subject to change and/or garbage headaches depending on your program design (you create memory inside the function for the return type and assign that address to a pointer variable, the pointer variable itself can be arbitrarily changed to point to another location in memory, e.t.c.). I'll expand on Luchian's last example by adding: imagine some somewhere else in your code you pass the ***z** variable to another function which then tries to use the memory pointed to by that address, you now have a pointer variable pointing to nothing which you then try to use.

It all boils down to good code design. If you understand the pros and cons of pointers and use them appropriately then you'll have no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Luchian Grigore has written some good description above. I would like to give you a small thought to further simplify your thinking.

When ever you pass a argument to a function in C, try to think what exactly goes on to the stack ( in case 1, actual integer variables gets pushed onto stack and in case 2 & 3 adresses of those integer variables gets pushed ), now to this combine that fact that changes made to variables on stack vanish as soon as the control returns from funciton and stack unwindes.

So in simple terms if you plan to change the varibales being passed inside the function and expect to use those changes later then consider passing the address of those varibles, else simply pass variables.

Answer (score -2):

For `int`, always pass by value unless it is not possible to do so. 
i.e `int returnSomething(int a, int b)`.

When you are passing some custom big `struct`, pass it and return it as a pointer unless it is not possible to do so.

Comment: What if you want to change the values of the arguments?

Comment: yeah, that would be one of the case where it is not possible to do so.

Comment: My downvote was because you said "always pass by value". I can't think of a reason for not being possible to do so... you can always pass an int by value.

Comment: It is always possible to pass by value and never say "never". Always explain the pros and cons and leave it to the programmer to decide.